# Get dimensions of numpy structured (i.e. record) array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Say I have a `numpy` structured array (a.k.a. record array):

```
record_types = np.dtype([
                ('date',object),  #00 - Timestamp
                ('lats',float),   #01 - Latitude
                ('lons',float),   #02 - Longitude
                ('vals',float),   #03 - Value
                ])

data = np.zeros(10, dtype=record_types)
```

If I try to call the shape attribute, I get `(10,)`

How can I do something like the following:

```
y, x = data.shape
```

To get `y = 10` and `x = 4`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the confusing things about structured arrays.

You basically have a (n-1)D array where each *item* is a C-like struct.

This type of structure allows for all kinds of useful things (easy file IO with binary formats, for example), but it's quite confusing for a lot of other use cases.  For what you're doing, you'd likely be better served by using `pandas` than directly using a structured array.

That having been said, here's how you'd get what you're asking:

```
def structured_shape(x):
    if len(x.dtype) > 0
        return list(x.shape) + [len(x.dtype)]
    else:
        return x.shape
```

Comment: I have yet to look into `pandas`, but this is another great reason. Thank you!

Comment: Plus one for recommending pandas while still answering the question.